# Formio connecting to other databases other than mongodb

Tags: formio

Anyone know if we can configure a different database than the default
mongodb database that shipped with formio? I found "formio-sql" and it seems to act as a connector to our own database where we have to create and maintain own database tables and configure them with actions. What I am actually looking for is whether formio can use different databases like Mysql to store the submitted data natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, it is not possible to use databases other than MongoDB to store submitted data natively.

The only option is by using 'Sql Connector' action via 'formio-sql' which you have seem to have found yourself.